# ExpressJs sends stack in production mode

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, environment-variables

I am trying to simulate production before going live, and I have the following setup

package.json

```
"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node dist/index.js",
```

*index.ts*

```
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV) // prints "production"
router.use(handleError);
```

*error-handler.ts*

```
import { serializeError } from 'serialize-error';

export function handleError(
  err: ResponseError,
  _req: Request,
  resp: Response,
  _next: NextFunction
): void {
  if (err) {
    resp.status(err.statusCode || 500).json(serializeError(err));
  }
}
```

With this setup, when there is an error request, I get the stack in the response, which I dont want.

If I add to the error handler function

```
  if (err) {
     if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { 
          delete err.stack;
          resp.status(err.statusCode || 500).json(serializeError(err));
     }
  }
```

then I dont get the stack. But isnt Express supposed to automatically remove the stack in production?

Comment: Express doesn't have a chance here because you're serializing the error object yourself and sending that.  So, you've taken over that job from Express.  The stack will still be in the error object itself.  That comes from the source of the error.

Comment: @jfriend00 ok thanks a lot for that comment. It made sense. I do remember I had some use for this serializer.. Is there anything in Express default functionalities besides this stack that my serializeError prevents me from benefiting from? 
I am thinking that if it's just for the stack, then I can use the workaround I proposed in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express doesn't have a chance here because you're serializing the error object yourself and sending that. So, you've taken over that job from Express. The stack will still be in the error object itself. That comes from the source of the error.

If you want to send the error stack in non-production mode, I would propose a modification of your proposal like this:

```
if (err) {
     if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { 
          delete err.stack;
     }
     resp.status(err.statusCode || 500).json(serializeError(err));
}
```

Though, I don't ever send the stack trace as part of the response.  Instead, I always log the error locally:

```
if (err) {
     console.log(err);
     delete err.stack;
     resp.status(err.statusCode || 500).json(serializeError(err));
}
```

> Is there anything in Express default functionalities besides this stack that my serializeError prevents me from benefiting from?

It's worth reading the [Express doc page on error handling](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html).  Their default handler attempts a different behavior if headers have already been sent (such as you encountered an error while stream a response) since your options are a lot more limited at that point.

They also force any `err.statusCode` that isn't 4xx or 5xx to 500 since they want to make sure it gets reported as an error status code.  You are allowing whatever is on the error object to go through.